# How to add image to only front page of Drupal 7?

Tags: 7, theming, media

How to add image to only front page of Drupal 7 website ?

So for now I have this code:

```
<div id="content-wrapper">
    <img src="/sites/default/files/Front_Page_Pic.png" width="100%"/>
    <?php
    if (!drupal_is_front_page()) {
        echo render($page['content']);
    } else {
        echo render($page['reference']);
    }
    ?>
</div>
```

But this means that on everypage it will show my image.

Any idea how can i fix it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is another approach:

- create "a" node (pick whatever content type you want), say it's node id is `123` (generated automatically by Drupal when you save it). Or add a "path" to it like `my_page_with_image`.
- include that image in that node and make sure your ***input filter*** that you use (i.e if you use "filtered HTML", which is what I'd recommend) accepts "images".
- set `node/123` as your frontpage (or `my_page_with_image` instead, if you added a path for it).

Next question? Maybe "***How do I set that page as my frontpage***"? ... Ask (via a new question, only 1 question per 'question' here ...) and pretty sure you'll get the answer to that question to ...

PS: What is so special about all your pages where you are considering using PHP for it's actual content? You are aware that using PHP for those things is in general NOT recommended, right? And that you have to be very carefull in which user "roles" will be allowed to create such pages ...

Answer (score 1):

Drupal has its own way to theming and displaying content , and its not easy so i suggest you to use modules in this case , so first of all install [Image Block](https://www.drupal.org/project/imageblock) module , you can now easily create a block containing a photo.
in the next step go to block configuration and set the block to be displayed only in front page ,  token may help you ;)

Answer (score 1):

**Another way**

1.Create a block add image and display on front page.

2.You can also create separate tpl file for front page.

Answer (score 0):

Add the page--front.tpl.php into your theme folder.
Print the image in this Tpl.

For further info on front page template files refer - [Customize the front page template](https://www.drupal.org/node/317461)

Comment: So as far as i know this is the code ?:
<img src="<?php print $directory; ?>/sites/default/files/Front_Page_Pic.png" />

?

Comment: Yes this would do it.

Comment: I get the fatal error:
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in /var/www/vhosts/httpdocs/sites/all/themes/mater/templates/page.tpl.php on line 124 
The line which i add this code.